# Adding a number to MySQL Value If Found in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to add a 1 ,2 or a 3 ect to the end of the username if it already exists. This is what I have so far, but I can't quite get it to add a number. It is simply inputting the username over and over.

```
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$username'");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($numRows > 0) {
   $i = 0;

   while ($name_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {

      $name = $name_arr['username'];       

      $after = substr($name, strlen($username));

      if (ctype_digit($after)) {

         if (($after = (int) $after) > $i) {

            $i = $after;

         }

      }

   }

   if ($i > 0) {
      $username .= $i;
   }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm still having trouble establishing a way to add a number to the end. Within my logic all I can think of is using the row count and using that number to append to the username if a duplicate exists. This is what I have so far. Any help is much appreciated. I've been stuck on this for two days now and can't quite find anything in my search on stackoverflow.

```
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$username'");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($numRows > 0) {
   $i = 0;

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

      $username = "$username";       

        if($counter > 0){
        $username = $usernamename[$count];
        $counter++;
        }
        else {
        $username == "$username";
        }


}
}
```

One more edit:

I think I may have overlooked a possible solution. Would just adding the id to the username be a solution worth thinking about? There can't be a duplicate there and it would make sense, right?

```
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$username'");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($numRows > 0) {
   $i = 0;

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

      $id = $row["id"];
      $username = $row['username'];       

        if($counter > 0){
        $username = '.$username.''.$id.';

        }
        else 
        $username == "$username";



}
}
```

The next update:

```
<?php

// Check to see there are posted variables coming into the script
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die ("No Post Variables");
// Initialize the $req variable and add CMD key value pair
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
// Read the post from PayPal
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Now Post all of that back to PayPal's server using curl, and validate everything with PayPal
// We will use CURL instead of PHP for this for a more universally operable script (fsockopen has issues on some environments)
//$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req);  // Make it a nice list in case we want to email it to ourselves for reporting

// Check that the result verifies
if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
    $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
} else {
    $req .= "\n\nData NOT verified from Paypal!";
    mail("chris@.com", "IPN interaction not verified", "$req", "From: chris@.com" );
    exit();
}

/* CHECK THESE 4 THINGS BEFORE PROCESSING THE TRANSACTION, HANDLE THEM AS YOU WISH
1. Make sure that business email returned is your business email
2. Make sure that the transaction’s payment status is “completed”
3. Make sure there are no duplicate txn_id
4. Make sure the payment amount matches what you charge for items. (Defeat Price-Jacking) */

// Check Number 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
if ($receiver_email != "chris@.com") {
    $message = "Investigate why and how receiver email is wrong. Email = " . $_POST['receiver_email'] . "\n\n\n$req";
    mail("chris@.com", "Receiver Email is incorrect", $message, "From: chris@.com" );
    exit(); // exit script
}
// Check number 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($_POST['payment_status'] != "Completed") {
    // Handle how you think you should if a payment is not complete yet, a few scenarios can cause a transaction to be incomplete
}
// Connect to database ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';
// Check number 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$this_txn = $_POST['txn_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE txn_id='$this_txn' LIMIT 1");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($numRows > 0) {
    $message = "Duplicate transaction ID occured so we killed the IPN script. \n\n\n$req";
    mail("chris@.com", "Duplicate txn_id in the IPN system", $message, "From: chris@.com" );
    exit(); // exit script
} 
// Check number 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$product_id_string = $_POST['custom'];
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
// Explode the string, make it an array, then query all the prices out, add them up, and make sure they match the payment_gross amount
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string); // Uses Comma(,) as delimiter(break point)
$fullAmount = 0;
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {

    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value); // Uses Hyphen(-) as delimiter to separate product ID from its quantity
    $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID
    $product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[1]; // Get the quantity
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM products WHERE id='$product_id' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $product_price = $row["price"];
    }
    $product_price = $product_price * $product_quantity;
    $fullAmount = $fullAmount + $product_price;
}
$fullAmount = number_format($fullAmount, 2);
$grossAmount = $_POST['mc_gross']; 
if ($fullAmount != $grossAmount) {
        $message = "Possible Price Jack: " . $_POST['payment_gross'] . " != $fullAmount \n\n\n$req";
        mail("chris@.com", "Price Jack or Bad Programming", $message, "From: chris@.com" );
        exit(); // exit script
} 

//
//
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

//now to always get unique username
$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
if ( ! uniqueName($username))
{
    $username = makeUniqueName($username);
}


//function to check if is the existing username
function uniqueName($username)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$username'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($numRows > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


//function to generate new unique username
function makeUniqueName($username)
{
    //serch username string for number at the end
    //regexp makes sure all preceeding zeroes go to first match group
    if (preg_match('/^(\S*?0*)?(\d+?)$/', $username, $match))
    {
        //we got digit from the end of string, just add 1 to the digit
        $username = $match[1] . ($match[2] + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        //no digit at the end of string, just add digit 1 at the end
        $username = $username . 1;
    }

if (uniqueName($username))
{
    return $username;
}

    return makeUniqueName($username);
}

// END ALL SECURITY CHECKS NOW IN THE DATABASE IT GOES ------------------------------------
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Homework - Examples of assigning local variables from the POST variables
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['payment_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$password = mt_rand(1000, 9999); 
$p_hash = md5($password);
$username = $_POST['makeUniqueName'];
 //

// Place the transaction into the database
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (product_id_array, payer_email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee, password, ip, username) 
   VALUES('$custom','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$payment_date','$mc_gross','$payment_currency','$txn_id','$receiver_email','$payment_type','$payment_status','$txn_type','$payer_status','$address_street','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country','$address_status','$notify_version','$verify_sign','$payer_id','$mc_currency','$mc_fee','$p_hash','$ip','$username')") or die ("unable to execute the query");
$to      = $payer_email;  
$subject = ' | Login Credentials';  
$message = ' 

Your officially all ready to go. To login use the information below.

Your account login information 
------------------------- 
Email: '.$payer_email.' 
Password: '.$password.' 
------------------------- 

You can now login at https://www..com/signin.php';  
$headers = 'From:noreply@.com' . "\r\n";  

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
mysql_close();
// Mail yourself the details
mail("chris@.com", "NORMAL IPN RESULT YAY MONEY!", $req, "From: chris@.com");

?>
```

Comment: ctype_digit returns true if the parameter is a digit - this will return false for names like "myusername" - meaning $i will remain at 0 and $username will not be appended to. Edit: Misread the code. Debug it and check the value of your variables and trace through your logic

Comment: thanks for the comment andrew. I'm a bit confused on how to reslove this. Would it be something as simple as removing the ctype if?

Comment: Well doesn't the username exist if the query returns a positive result? If so then you don't need all your checks, just append a number.

Comment: Where are you assigning '$user_query', I don't see that anywhere? (not that thats your problem, just wondering)

Comment: what would you have there instead @KyleK ?

Comment: $name_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) .... since $sql, is your query variable...

Comment: oohh I see what you mean...i did change that . I'm not sure my reasoning, but I'm sure I'll figure it out later if an error occurs. 

I'm still not understanding how to correct this. Which checks are you referring to @Revent ?

Comment: Also you assign $after to $i. $after is the last digit of the existing username so you should either increment $after inside the if block or increment $i before you append to $username

Comment: holy cow I'm confused.

Comment: A side note if the same username is requested 9 times the next value generated by your script (with the changes I mentioned) would be 10, as in "username10" - the next time that username is requested your code would get the last digit, 0, and increment that to 1 but "username1" would exist.

Comment: oh boy, I better rethink my implementation. Am I making this harder than it has to be?

Comment: IMO if the username exists you should inform the user and let me choose another, instead of changing their requested username to username + digit

Comment: its an assigned username rather than choosing username similar to how my username here has an addition in the grand scheme of things. Though it does appear as only Chris

Comment: I've just updated the original message with my next attempt

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can do it on MySql side in one go with a query like this

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT('$username', SUBSTRING(MAX(username), CHAR_LENGTH('$username') + 1) * 1 + 1), '$username') username
  FROM transactions
 WHERE username REGEXP '$username([0-9]+)?$'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/711ca/10)** demo

**On a side note:** In your code you are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` extensions calls.  First you make a `mysql_query()` call then you do `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Stick with one. Preferably `mysqli_*` since `mysql_*` deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked Psudo-PHP:

```
// insert code before determining if the desired $userName $isTaken
$newName = "";
if ($isTaken) {
    $i = 1;
    do {
        $newName = $userName . $i;
        $query = "SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$newName'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($numRows == 0) $i = 0;
    } while ($i != 0)
}
```

If you want to avoid multiple queries, search for everyting LIKE the username and sort it yourself, but depending on the scale, it likely isn't going to be that expensive.

Comment: hi @Conexion i'm a bit new to this and trying to make sense of it. I'm confused as to what you meant by insert code ect. are we talking about containing it within the if numrows block?

Comment: Before the code I posted, you'll want to do a quick check to see if the username is already in use. If it is in use, then go through the while loop checking and adding one each pass.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to always get unique username. If there is digit at the end of string to make unique it will add +1, and recheck if unique, if not it will do it again and again until unique name is found. If there is no digit at the end it will add 1 at the end and recheck like before until unique not existing name is found.

```
$dbConn = new mysqli($host, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

//now to always get unique username
$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
if ( ! isUniqueName($username))
{
    $username = makeUniqueName($username);
}


//function to check if is the existing username
function isUniqueName($username)
{
    global $dbConn;

    $sql = mysqli_query($dbConn, "SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$username'");
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if ($numRows > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


//function to generate new unique username
function makeUniqueName($username)
{
    //serch username string for number at the end
    //regexp makes sure all preceeding zeroes go to first match group
    if (preg_match('/^(\S*?0*)?(\d+?)$/', $username, $match))
    {
        //we got digit from the end of string, just add 1 to the digit
        $username = $match[1] . ($match[2] + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        //no digit at the end of string, just add digit 1 at the end
        $username = $username . 1;
    }

    if (isUniqueName($username))
    {
        return $username;
    }

    return makeUniqueName($username);
}
```

Comment: i'm getting an error with this function :


       Call to undefined function uniqueName()

Comment: hi @Aleksandar I'm getting the error 

Call to undefined function uniqueName()


Any help understanding this is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I called not defined function, here I made edit to correct: if ( ! uniqueName <> isUniqueName($username))

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar I'm not quiet able to get it to post. I'm getting a blank within the database where as before I was getting the payer_mail minus everything after @. Any tips on what may be happening? I've updated the original post to show what I'm working with now.

Comment: I didn't test this, is prob becose mysql connection is not in the scope inside isUniqueName function. Now is changed it to MySQLi example, as mysql will not be supported from php 5.5. Try it out now.

Comment: Nope...I'm still getting a blank. What would be posted at the bottom of the update script above? I'm using username..is this correct?

Comment: I think we're on the right path because I believe if I enter uniqueusername I get a number so that made sense. I believe the number increases. I tried it up to 3, but there was never the payer_email minus everything after @